# Removing RKHunter (installed with apt) when RKhunter Installed from source

Tags: rkhunter

I installed rkhunter from source (1.40 I think) and then later updated to 1.4.2 from source (as there is no app update function in rkhunter and the latest version in apt is old) however that means I have the old version at /usr/bin/rkhunter and the new at /usr/local/bin/rkhunter. As long as I remember to use the right path (or ensure /usr/local/bin is higher in $PATH) it seems ok, but I'm not sure having two versions of the rkhunter at the same time and using the same config file is a good idea. So! Is there a way to remove the old and keep the new and not mess up the config?

Best I can think of is backup the config, remove with apt, reinstall for source, restore config and run --propupd to set the database

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
From new info:
1.installed from source.
2.Installed from package

Assuming you still have copy of the original source you used i would still try:
Backing up the config then

`make uninstall`

or

`sudo make uninstall`

using the Original 1.40 source.

at which point making sure the package version is correctly installed with:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure rkhunter` on debian based systems or:
`sudo yum reinstall rkhunter` for red hat bases systems

The configuration should stay intact but i did also advise backing up just in case.

Comment: Apologies @cormpadre - I used "from source" incorrectly; I meant to say the pre-packaged build from source forge (tgz). I was attempting to make the difference between apt and non-package installations.

Comment: edited answer hope it helps, first remove the source install completly then just reinstall the package version. that is best way to ensure its cleaned fully.

Comment: Cheers. That seems the best/only way. Fortunately I maintain a cloned version in vbox for testing on!